# ScannerError when parsing a list with scalars that have colon

Tags: ruamel.yaml

- Python 3.7 (Windows)
- ruamel.yaml 0.16.10
- ruamel.yaml.clib 0.2.0

I have a fairly simple YAML file that I'm loading:

```yaml
test: [C:\Users\Administrator, C:\Documents]
```

Here is example Python code that loads this YAML file (called test.yaml)

```py
import ruamel.yaml
yaml_object = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
with open('test.yaml') as f:
    data = yaml_object.load(f)
```

results in error

> ruamel.yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a plain scalar found
>
> unexpected ':'

Interestingly, if I just call safe_load directly
ie.

```py
data = ruamel.yaml.safe_load(f)
```

this works fine.

Also, if I change the source file to use the dash style of list
ie.

```yaml
test:
   - C:\Users\Administrator
   - C:\Documents
```

This also works with `yaml_object` and direct `safe_load`

Is there something I need to do to `yaml_object` so that it will work with the bracket-style list?

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe').load(document)
```

in ruamel.yaml, you will invoke the C extension, i.e. libyaml,  (assuming it can be loaded) and that is libyaml which has unfixed behavior with regards to colons not followed by non-space in keys

This behaviour was fixed in both the round-trip loader:

```
ruamel.yaml.YAML().load(document)
```

as well as in the pure Python safe version

```
ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe', pure=True).load(document)
```

this latter form is, what you should use, and it is mostly equivalent to `ruamel.yaml.safe_load(document)` (which you should not use anymore).

So the behavior is to be expected (at least until I replace the C extension) and IIRC this is not the only bug in that libyaml compared to ruamel.yaml using pure Python.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and solved it by running my dictionary (before dumping to a file) through this function I made after inspecting some of the code in ruamel.yaml:

```
import ruamel.yaml
import ruamel.yaml.scalarstring

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()


def format_lists_in_block_style_if_colon_found(val):
    """Convert all lists with a ':' in them to block style."""
    if isinstance(val, list):
        for ind, ele in enumerate(val):
            ele = format_lists_in_block_style_if_colon_found(ele)
            if isinstance(ele, str) and ':' in ele:
                val._yaml_format.set_block_style()  # most important
                # this ScalarString format step is optional if only using ruamel, but mandatory if using pyyaml CLoader.
                if '"' in ele:  # for readability.
                    ele = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.SingleQuotedScalarString(ele)
                else:
                    ele = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString(ele)
            val[ind] = ele
    elif isinstance(val, dict):
        for k in val:
            val[k] = format_lists_in_block_style_if_colon_found(val[k])
    return val


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML
with open('yourfile.yml') as f:
    dict_ = yaml().load(f.read())

dict_ = format_lists_in_block_style_if_colon_found(dict_)

with open('yourfile.yml', 'w') as fw:
    yaml().dump(dict_, fw)

with open('yourfile.yml') as f2:
    # should work now!
    dict_ = yaml(typ='safe').load(f2.read())

import yaml as pyyaml
with open('yourfile.yml') as f2:
    # should work now!
    dict_ = pyyaml.load(f2.read(), Loader=pyyaml.CLoader)  # use Loader instead of CLoader if needed
```

I did this because I need the fastest CLoader I can get, typ='safe' was failing, and even worse, pyyaml's regular CLoader was loading in values like [23:50] in as [1430] which was not fun to find. pyyaml CLoader runs about 20% faster than ruamel.yaml, but I'd rather my code fail obviously than have weird, hard-to-find behavior.

Hope this helps!

Side note for ruamel's author Anthon - keep up the great work! Discovered ruamel earlier this week, and it's already been a lifesaver :)